# This form has been disabled due to suspicious content error message in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Getting this error message:

> Invalid Form
>
> Our apologies, this form has been disabled due to suspicious content. If you believe you have received this message in error, please contact the original form author.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. It looks like you are trying to collect a field with sensitive information which we typically block to prevent phishing attacks. Try to remove some of the fields from your form that are collecting personal information.